# How to take two-dimensional array of ints and return two-dimensional array of chars?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm hoping to read in the int values and create a new array with char values corresponding to each int value. Could anyone point me in the right direction / or recommend something for me to study/read?

I'm over my head trying to understand how to write this.  Here is what I have so far.

```
    int[][] Grades = {{90, 54, 32, 25}, {65, 80, 72, 26}};

    for (int i = 0; i < Grades.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < Grades[i].length; j++) {

            if (Grades[i][j] >= 90) {

            }
            if (Grades[i][j] >= 80) {

            }
            if (Grades[i][j] >= 70) {

            }
            if (Grades[i][j] >= 60) {

            } else {

            }
            System.out.print(Grades[i][j] + "\t");

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a two dimensional `char` array and save the corresponding grade char.

```
    int[][] Grades = {{90, 54, 32, 25}, {65, 80, 72, 26}};
    char[][] result=new char[Grades.length][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < Grades.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < Grades[i].length; j++) {

            if (Grades[i][j] >= 90) {
               result[i][j]='A'; 
            }
            ....
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer such a nooby question. I have been looking at this for far too long, so i figured it would not hurt to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create character array in this way,

```
char output[][] = new char[Grades.length][4];
```

and assign values to it in this way,

```
output[i][j] = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must use "else if".

```
char[][] r = new char[Grades.length][4];

for (int i = 0; i < Grades.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < Grades[i].length; j++) {

        if (Grades[i][j] >= 90) {
           r[i][j] = 'A';
        }
        else if (Grades[i][j] >= 80) {
           r[i][j] = 'B';
        }
        else if (Grades[i][j] >= 70) {
          r[i][j] = 'C';
        }
```

Comment: I realized that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this all inside one function? I think you should be building a new two dimensional char array and then returning that from a function. Take the two dimensional int array as a parameter.

Comment: Woops im late haha, started typing this and by the time I was done your answer was there!